# PHP Best way to stop constructor

Tags: php, security, constructor, exit

I am dealing with stop the constructor.

```
public function __construct()
{
   $q = explode("?",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $this->page = $q[0];

   if (isset($q[1]))
      $this->querystring = '?'.$q[1];

   if ($this->page=='/login') {include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pages/login.php');
      // I WANT TO EXIT CONSTRUCTOR HERE
}
```

There are function to stop/exit constructor :

**die()** , **exit()**, **break()** and **return false**

I am using return false but i am confusing about security. What is the best way to exit constructor ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Throw an exception

Comment: ```throw new Exception('Exiting the constructor');```

Comment: You can read about Exceptions in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), with examples shown there

Comment: What do you mean by "exit"? What's the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A full example, because questions should have an accepted answer:

Throw an exception in the constructor like this:

```
class SomeObject {
    public function __construct( $allIsGoingWrong ) {
      if( $allIsGoingWrong ) {
        throw new Exception( "Oh no, all is going wrong! Abort!" );
      }
    }
}
```

Then when you create the object, catch the error like this:

```
try {
  $object = new SomeObject(true);
  // if you get here, all is fine and you can use $object
}
catch( Exception $e ) {
  // if you get here, something went terribly wrong.
  // also, $object is undefined because the object was not created
}
```

If for whatever reason you do not catch the error anywhere, it will result in a Fatal Exception that will crash the entire page, which will explain that you "failed to catch an exception" and will show you the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the constructor **without** actually fatally crashing the site, without you catching anything, then you can simply `return`. You may want to trigger an error that is not fatal and then exist with return

```
public function __construct()
{
   if ( $shit_is_wrong ) {

     trigger_error('Shit went wrong', E_USER_NOTICE);

     // in WordPress you should do this instead.
     wp_trigger_error(__METHOD__, 'Shit went wrong');

     return;
   }
}
```